# Git is merges branches without specifying it (git pull)

Tags: git

Some time ago I've created the branch "B", done some commits and pushed to bitbucket. In another place I've already had another version of the same repo, on branch "master", here I just made `git pull` and somehow the branch "master" was not behind the branch "B", they were at the exact same commit.

How is this possible? Or what I've done wrong with git to behave this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git pull
```

Is the same than:

```
git fetch
git merge
```

If you want to download remote branches without merging, you should use:

```
git fetch
```

Look at:
[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: oh, thanks then I think that was the problem.. I should use git fetch more.. In this case there was no problem but if I had "production" and "development" and merging them could do some problems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you did and what you expected from your explanation, but `git pull` does a `git fetch` and `git merge`, it is possible that the merge simply had no conflicts so to you it seemed like they were at the same position.